# Lotus Notes 8.5: % in attachment file name. Bad request: Http request contains a malformed escape sequence

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript, lotus

Some attachments have % in their file name.
SO when I access the attachment file with the URL, it returns back with Cod 400.

Reason: Http request contains a malformed escape sequence.

I have been searching around and saw somebody say Lotus Notes does not allow to access file with % in their name.

I saw a solution which is put HTTPAllowDecodedUrlPercent=1 in notes.ini file.

Firstly, I don't know where to find the notes.ini file.
I saw one in IBM\Lotus\Domino\  another in IBM\Lotus\Notes\

Actually, I have tried too add the line into both files. But nothing happened. I still got the same error.
Is it because I did it in the wrong way? Or is there anything else I can do?

Comment: Are you encoding the % character?  An attachment named foo%bar.gif should be foo%25bar.gif in the URL.  Also, please include a sample URL that demonstrates the problem.  That will help folks trying to reproduce this.

Comment: The reason that you have two notes.ini files is because you have both the Lotus Notes client and Lotus Domino server software instlaled on the same server. Your question is about the Lotus Domino HTTP server, therefore the notes.ini file that you want to modify is the one in the IBM\Lotus\Domino folder.

Comment: But nothing happened. >> Yes Domino won't update it's configuration until you send to the domino server the command "tell http refresh" (hoping it's enough, if not you will have to restart the server). NB to send a command to server use the Administrator client, Server, server console.

Comment: I didn't do anything, but after about a day after I changed the notes.ini. It starts working. So I am guessing the http refresh must happen at some point.

Answer (score 2):

You would need to update the notes.ini on the server if you are working on a server.  You can update it also from Domino Administrator if you have access to that.  See this snippet from Notes Help...

> 1. From the Domino Administrator, open the Domino Directory and click the Configuration tab.
> 2. To edit an existing Configuration Settings document, highlight it and then click Edit Configuration. To create a new configuration
>      document, highlight the server for which the Configuration Settings
>      document will apply, then click Add Configuration.
> 3. To modify NOTES.INI settings on the server, click the NOTES.INI Settings tab. This tab lists a number of current settings in the
>      server's NOTES.INI file.
> 4. To add or change a setting, click Set/Modify Parameters to display all settings that you can set in the Configuration Settings document.
>      Select the setting(s) you want to add/modify.
> 5. Save and close the document.

Like Dave said, try and give us a little more information.